# optional second directory in htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi
im wanting to write a mod redirect which handles the following:

`www.domain.co.uk/brands`
rewrites to `www.domain.co.uk/index.php?p=brands`

`www.domain.co.uk/brands/5`
rewrites to `www.domain.co.uk/index.php?p=brands&go=5`

Can this be achieved in one line without a conditional statement?

I have written this, but the second line is ignored:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php\?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^((.*)/*)(.*)\.html$ index.php?p=$1&go=$2 [L]
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule  (.*)(/(.*))?$  index.php?p=$1&go=$3 [L]
```

should do it.

The reason your second rule fails is, you are matching one character (`.`) followed by a `/` at the start of the string, so immediately any urls with more than one character before the first slash will fail. You are also insisting that the url ends with `html` but in your examples they don't. Also for the future, remember `.` matches any single character so you probably meant to escape the `.` before `html`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to me that the first rule would match both versions, and rewrite `www.domain.co.uk/brands/5` to `www.domain.co.uk/index.php?p=brands/5` -- and then the `[L]` flag makes the matching stop. It wouldn't match the second rule after the rewrite, anyway.

The second regexp has an asterisk too many (after the slash) and one set of parens too many as well, but if you fix that and move it above the other one, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the order. As a general practice you must have most specific rules first and most generic as last. Try this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)\.html$ /index.php?p=$1&go=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will redirect URI of '/brands/5.html' to `/index.php?p=brands&go=5` and a URI of '/brands.html' to `/index.php?p=brands`